# Find nearest neighbor by distance

Tags: python, django, ajax, geodjango

I have a problem in my code to find the nearest neighbor, I am building a route optimizer for people who travel on foot, now if I tell you, the error that I am experiencing.
First I have a model in django with the following fields:

```
# Create your models here.
class Pdv(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150, verbose_name="Nombre del PDV:")
    direction = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Dirección:")
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Razón Social:')
    pdv_code =  models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='codigo de PDV:', null=True, blank=True)
    pdv_channel = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Canal de PDV:')
    chain_pdv = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Cadena:', null=True, blank=True)
    time_pdv = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Tiempo en PDV:', null=True, blank=True)
    frequency_pdv = models.CharField(max_length=4, verbose_name='Frecuencia PDV:')
    latitude = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Latitud:")
    longitude = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Longitud:")
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Ciudad:')
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Departamento:')
    customers = models.ForeignKey(Customers, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name="Cliente:")   

     # We create the str that returns us when the class is called
     def __str__(self):
        # self.datos = [self.name, self.direction, self.latitude, self.longitude, self.city, self.department]
        return self.name
```

In the model I store the coordinates separately, guaranteeing that the client correctly stores the data of each point.

In the view I am building a process where:

1. Find the northernmost point of all points and make it as the reference point
2. Order them by distance from least to greatest.
3. Perform a time validation.
4. If true add the point to a list of points (To draw lines between the reference point and the current point)
5. If the point does not comply, convert it into the reference point and eliminate it from the query
6. Go back to 2.

I have the above segmented like this:
I take the reference point

```
pdv_ref = Pdv.objects.filter(customers_id=request.POST['idclient']).order_by('-latitude')[0]
```

I define a function that performs the measurement of the points

```
def calcular_distancia(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    # Radio de la Tierra en kilómetros
    radio_tierra = 6372

     # Convertir grados a radianes
     lat1_r = math.radians(lat1)
     lon1_r = math.radians(lon1)
     lat2_r = math.radians(lat2)
     lon2_r = math.radians(lon2)

      # Calcular la diferencia de latitud y longitud
      dif_lat = lat2_r - lat1_r
      dif_lon = lon2_r - lon1_r

      # Calcular la distancia utilizando la fórmula del haversine
      a = math.sin(dif_lat / 2) ** 2 + math.cos(lat1_r) * math.cos(lat2_r) * math.sin(dif_lon / 2) ** 2
      c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1 - a))
      distancia = radio_tierra * c

      # Devolver la distancia en kilómetros
      return distancia
```

I define some variables to use

```
            pdv_global = []
            excel_pdv = []
            cant_people = 1
            minutos_ = 0
            total_horas_ = td()
            poligono = 1
```

The following code makes me or I try to make the previously named.

```
                while len(list_pdv_all) > 0:
                    # Calcular la distancia y el tiempo de recorrido para cada par de puntos y almacenarlos en un diccionario
                    distancias = [(p, calcular_distancia(pdv_ref.latitude, pdv_ref.longitude, p.latitude, p.longitude)) for p in list_pdv_all.order_by('-latitude')]

                    # Ordenar los puntos por distancia de menor a mayor distancia
                    pdv_ordenados = sorted(distancias, key=lambda x: x[1])

                    # Iterar sobre los puntos ordenados y agregar los que cumplen con la condición
                    for point, distance in pdv_ordenados:
                        poligono_str = f"poligono {poligono}"
                        if pdv_ref != point:
                            hora_ = dt.strptime(point.time_pdv, "%H:%M:%S").time()
                            total_horas_ += td(hours=hora_.hour, minutes=hora_.minute,
                                            seconds=hora_.second) * int(point.frequency_pdv)
                            total_horas_ += td(minutes=int(translado))
                            minutos_ = total_horas_.total_seconds() / 60
                            valor_ = minutos_/11520
                            print(valor_)

                            if valor_ <= float(1.05) and distance <=60:
                                pdv_global.append([[pdv_ref.latitude, pdv_ref.longitude], [point.latitude, point.longitude]])
                                
                                excel_pdv.append({"Nombre_PDV": point.name, "Frecuencia": point.frequency_pdv,  "Ciudad": point.city, "Departamento":point.department, "Dirección":point.direction, "Tiempo_pdv": point.time_pdv})

                                excel_pdv[-1]['Poligono'] = poligono_str
                                
                                list_pdv_all = list_pdv_all.exclude(name=point.name)

                            # Si la condición no se cumple, actualizar el punto de referencia y continuar
                            else:
                                pdv_ref = point
                                # pdv_ref = list_pdv_all.order_by('-latitude')[0]
                                excel_pdv.append({"Nombre_PDV": pdv_ref.name, "Frecuencia": pdv_ref.frequency_pdv, "Ciudad": pdv_ref.city, "Departamento": pdv_ref.department, "Dirección": pdv_ref.direction, "Tiempo_pdv": pdv_ref.time_pdv})
                                poligono += 1
                                poligono_str = f"poligono {poligono}"
                                excel_pdv[-1]['Poligono'] = poligono_str
                                total_horas_ = td()
                                cant_people += 1
                                valor_ = 0
                                # minutos_ = 0
                                break
                        else:
                            list_pdv_all = list_pdv_all.exclude(name=point.name)
```

It turns out that the previous code works halfway, I can't understand how to improve it, what should I do to solve why the polylines are crossing me if there are closest points, how should I focus so that when ordering the points, I do it in a way that is north to south, or which would be the way that works best for me for now I am interested in solving the issue of why I take points that are further away, in the following image it is evident how the lines come out mounted on others if there are points closer.

[image]

I hope you can help me, and I am already making myself understand, thanks in advance.

Comment: Just curious - What are you using to Map it? Is that a python package?

Comment: to map the points, serialize them and to change the icons if it's a python package and leaflet is called leaflet.awesome-markers, I don't know if that's your question.